expo-camera black screen on Android emulator despite proper permissions
I'm working on a React Native app using Expo, and I've ensured that the app has the required camera permissions. It works perfectly on a physical device, but when I try to use the app on an Android emulator, all I see is a black screen where the camera feed should be.
I've experimented with the following Android emulator camera settings, but none of them have resolved the issue:

Virtual Scene
Emulated
Webcam

I've attached a screenshot of my current emulator camera settings:

How can I get the camera feed to display properly on the emulator?

Not sure, but you can not rely on the emulator to use phone hardware.
